# Allocating id/factor/categories based on a group of values for each factor

Tags: r, data.table, categories

I have a large data table like the following:

```
id var1 var2
1   1   a
2   2   d
3   6   d
4   4   b
5   6   d
6   8   a
```

I need to assign a category in `var2` based on the values in `var1`. The categories do not follow any order with respect to `var1` values included in each category. For instance:

```
lista <- c(1,5,7)
listb <- c(4,9)
listd <- c(2,6)
```

I have tried two approaches unsuccessfully.
Using the `which` function:

`which: DT[which(var1 %in% lista), var2 := "a"]` and so on for the `listb` and `listd`.

It also didn't work the `function approach` (which may also be too slow for my large data table as it would have many `elseif` clauses). I wrote:

```
matchfun <- function(value){
  if (var1 %in% lista){
    value <- as.character(a)} else {
    return(value)}}
```

Any idea or comment on how to allocate factor/categories to group of values is very welcome.

Comment: Sorry, var2 is what I want to get but it is not in the initual dataset.

Comment: Put your classification into a data.table, like `mything = rbindlist( list( data.table(var2="a",var1=lista),data.table(var2="b",var1=listb),data.table(var2="d",var1=listd)))`, then set the key and merge.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd suggest a merge here. Let `DT` be your original data table.

```
DT <- data.table(id=1:6,var1=c(1,2,6,4,6,8))
```

First, you need to store your mapping in a table:

```
matchDT <- rbindlist(list( 
  data.table(var1=lista,var2="a"),
  data.table(var1=listb,var2="b"),
  data.table(var1=listd,var2="d")
))
```

Then you can merge, optionally setting `id` as the key afterward to restore the original sorting.

```
setkey(DT,var1)
DT[matchDT,var2:=var2,nomatch=FALSE]
setkey(DT,id)
```

The result is

```
   id var1 var2
1:  1    1    a
2:  2    2    d
3:  3    6    d
4:  4    4    b
5:  5    6    d
6:  6    8   NA
```

The last value is `NA` because your `lista` object doesn't contain `8` (but should).